# How to error handle Invoke-Command over SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh, powershell-remoting, invoke-command, powershell-7.0

I'm currently working with a script that utilizes the Invoke-Command over SSH as shown below. While it works well, I'm looking to implement exception handling, specifically for scenarios where the remote server is not reachable.
`Invoke-Command -HostName '192.168.100.1' -ScriptBlock { Write-Output "Hi" }`

When the remote server is not reachable, I receive the following error message: "ssh: connect to host 192.168.100.1 port 22: Connection timed out".

The challenge is that the script just halts and I have no option to manually abort it. So as the script just stops I cannot check for this error message in a if clause or smth. to handle this as the following code just does not get executed.

Is there any recommended approach or fix to implement proper exception handling in such cases?

**(Due to special Network enviornment I need to use remote Powershell over SSH so because ot that the -HostName instead of -ComputerName Parameter is used.)*

I tried redirecting the standard error stream (2) to the standard output stream by appending "2>&1" but still the script just halts and nothing gets saved into the variable.

`$result = Invoke-Command -HostName '192.168.100.1' -ScriptBlock { Write-Output "Hi" } 2>&1`

Comment: Invoke-Command returns a response.  Check the response.  If you get a bad response terminate the script.  Don't write an an output that cannot be used to stop the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = Invoke-Command -HostName '192.168.100.1' -ScriptBlock { Write-Output "Hi" } -ConnectingTimeout 5000 -ErrorAction STOP
```

By adding **-ConnectingTimeout** Parameter the command does not result in a stuck script and throws an error after the specified time. By adding -ErrorAction STOP and putting it into a try-catch block I was able to handle an unsuccessfull connection.

```
try {
    Invoke-Command -HostName '192.168.100.1' -ScriptBlock { Write-Output "Hi" } -ConnectingTimeout 5000 -ErrorAction STOP    
}
catch {
    $_
}
```

Thanks to Rich M. and MotoX80 from Microsoft Forum for providing the solution. Here our disussion about my issue: [How to error handle Invoke-Command over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1454844/how-to-error-handle-invoke-command-over-ssh?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1385332)